# Is there a fast way to fill NA values between gaps (possibly multiple) and only if the gap is below a certain size?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `DataFrame` with `id`s and `date`s. I would like to create another `DataFrame` which lists whether that `id` exists in a given month, over a pre-defined period of time (Say all of 2018). Further, if there are any existence gaps of 2 months or smaller, I would like to fill them in.

I figured I'd include the first part incase there's a better solution from the beginning. Here's the starting `df`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3],
                 'date': ['2018-02-01', '2018-03-12', '2018-05-10', 
                         '2018-10-10', '2018-11-04', '2018-06-07', '2018-07-07', 
                         '2018-09-16', '2018-02-02']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

To get it an existence `df_exist` I create a new column `id_exists` and merge with a tiled time-period `df_per`

```
df['id_exists'] = True
per = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', freq='MS')

df_per = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.tile(df.id.unique(), len(per)),
    'Period': np.repeat(per,df.id.nunique())})
df_exist = df_per.merge(df, left_on=['id', df_per.Period.dt.year, df_per.Period.dt.month],
             right_on=['id', df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month], how='left').drop(columns='date').fillna(False)

#      Period  id  id_exists
#0 2018-01-01   1      False
#1 2018-01-01   2      False
#2 2018-01-01   3      False
#3 2018-02-01   1       True
#4 2018-02-01   2      False
```

I've decided to `fillna` with `False` because that allows me to use the function below and `cumsum`, but certainly if there is a solution that makes use of having `NaN`s that's just as good.

Now I've defined a function which seems to do what I want: The index comparisons ensure I don't fill things on either edge, and the comparison with gap_size makes sure I'm only filling the small gaps. The if-else makes sure it works properly whether or not the first entry is True or False in the existence `df`.

```
def FillGaps(df, gap_size):
    gb = df.groupby(df.id_exists.cumsum()).size()

    if df.id_exists.values[0] == False:
        to_fill = gb[(gb.index > gb.index.min()) & (gb.index < gb.index.max()) &
            (gb.values <= gap_size)].index.values
    else:
        to_fill = gb[(gb.index < gb.index.max()) & (gb.values <= gap_size)].index.values

    df.loc[df.id_exists.cumsum().isin(to_fill), 'id_exists'] = True
    return df

df_exist = df_exist.groupby('id').apply(lambda df: FillGaps(df, gap_size=2))
```

However, it's pretty slow on a large `DataFrame`. Any ideas on how to make this faster? It didn't look like any of the built in `fillna` methods worked for this type of situation filling gaps, with the possibility of multiple gaps.

Here's the expected output. (I've done some merges so it's not formatted as an annoyingly long table). The point is that none of the edges get disturbed, only gaps of 2 months or less were filled and it didn't fail for `id==3` where there was only one value to begin with.

```
       Period  id_1  id_exists_1  id_2  id_exists_2  id  id_exists
0  2018-01-01     1        False     2        False   3      False
1  2018-02-01     1         True     2        False   3       True
2  2018-03-01     1         True     2        False   3      False
3  2018-04-01     1         True     2        False   3      False
4  2018-05-01     1         True     2        False   3      False
5  2018-06-01     1        False     2         True   3      False
6  2018-07-01     1        False     2         True   3      False
7  2018-08-01     1        False     2         True   3      False
8  2018-09-01     1        False     2         True   3      False
9  2018-10-01     1         True     2        False   3      False
10 2018-11-01     1         True     2        False   3      False
11 2018-12-01     1        False     2        False   3      False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```py
month = df.date - pd.Timedelta('1 day') * (df.date.dt.day - 1)
df_exist = df.id.astype(str).str.get_dummies().groupby(month).sum() != 0

def fill_gaps(arr):
    notnan, = (~np.isnan(arr)).nonzero()
    return np.nan if not notnan.size else arr[notnan[-1]]

date_range = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', freq='MS')
rolling = df_exist.reindex(date_range).rolling(window=2, min_periods=1)
result = rolling.apply(fill_gaps).fillna(False).astype(bool)
result[date_range > month.max()] = False
```

The first part should be much faster than doing the joins manually. The second part makes use of rolling API for dataframes.

The output looks like this:

```py
                1      2      3
2018-01-01  False  False  False
2018-02-01   True  False   True
2018-03-01   True  False  False
2018-04-01   True  False  False
2018-05-01   True  False  False
2018-06-01  False   True  False
2018-07-01  False   True  False
2018-08-01  False   True  False
2018-09-01  False   True  False
2018-10-01   True  False  False
2018-11-01   True  False  False
2018-12-01  False  False  False
```

which seems to match the results in your example.

Comment: while it works for the first part, it doesn't seem to help with the root of the problem; how to fill the gaps between existence periods. It's not just just a simple replace `NaN` with `False`. Even if I reindexed, in the above output I'd need to replace `2018-04-01` with `True` for `id==1` and `False` for `id==2` and `id==3`. A simple `fillna` doesn't work because it's not just a pad, or an fffill, I don't want to mess up the edges, and I only want to propagate the True value through the entire gap IF the gap is under a given size. I don't want to partially fill if the gap is too large.

Comment: And in the case that I choose a gap size large enough, say 6 months, I would even need to change some of the non-`NaN` values that are `False` in your output to `True`

Comment: @ALollz I must have missed the second part of the question indeed; I've updated the solution.